# How to word a written notice that an employee is claiming more hours than worked ( employee works remote )

Tags: management, manager, project-management, unprofessional-behavior

I work at a tech company and we have an employee that works remote and is calming more hours than worked, how can I write a written notice in a proper way. He is a good employee but his hours are just wrong and my boss will not approve them.

Comment: Are you a supervisor?  How do you know the hours aren't correct?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a note to the employee to tell him you know his hours claimed are wrong? Or to your boss, to make him aware of the situation?

Comment: yes, I'm the project manager and I work with him directly and I know those a hours are not correct he is claiming 250 hours for 10/1 to 10/31...that's 7500 dollars ...Thanks for you help btw.

Comment: @NicoleOlander That timeframe has 21 working days, 250 hours would be 12 hour days or roughly 60 hour weeks. That's not out of the realm of possibility. Do you have a process in place where hourly employees have to get approval to work overtime? Do you have a system for employees to log their time? Does the employee give you a breakdown of the hours or just a big total at the end?

Comment: so this guy works out of India and is only on slack at night  ...i can see when he is on and his work . he has admitted that he has had a vacation of 4 days off and weekend off ( which we do not work )

Comment: @Nicole Olander: Re "...only on slack at night", is being on slack (whatever that is) a prerequisite for doing whatever work the employee is doing?  Certainly I can do work (software development) without being on line, and sometimes without even having a computer turned on.

Answer (score 3):

Consider starting with a conversation or simple inquiry on the hours seem off.  Tell him his hours seem off and you need them confirmed.

Have you had any conversations or email on the matter in the past?

If it is a formal written notice then you need to get legal / HR in involved.

Then as far as wording it "these hours seem wrong to me - unless you can provide proof then I will not approve them".

Comment: Its kinda confusing , I guess you can kinda say I'm the hr for my department but technically I am the project manager and I approve all hours.

Comment: no I have never had this issue before and is actually a good employee .

Comment: No it's not a formal written notice and hr does know they asked me to sign approved hours and I told them i do not approve and hr asked me to let him know . thanks for your help btw